# WebSphere and StaleConnectionException

Tags: java, websphere, sqlexception, reconnect

I've encountered a StaleConnectionException in my J2ee application. I've studied (and searched) on and I have found a solution.

Here it is.

```
  public static Connection getConnection() {
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
      if (ds == null) ds = (DataSource) new Utility.makeLookup();
      conn = ds.getConnection();
      conn.setAutoCommit(false);

      //  Check quality of return connection
      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
      stmt.executeQuery("Select 1 from dual");
      stmt.close();

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        try {
          //  Recovery
          ds = (DataSource) new Utility.makeLookup();
          conn = ds.getConnection();
          conn.setAutoCommit(false);
          return conn;
        } catch (Throwable t2) { /* RIP */ }
    }

    return conn;
  }
```

I don't like this solution because i have a first lag of 6 seconds at first method call if I have to manage StaleConnectionException.

I've made a workaround: test the connection at the start of a new browser session, but I don't like this too.

There's something better that I can implement?

Thank you in advance.

Quack

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same exception for one application. I got rid of the problem by making following settings in websphere admin console. I am using webphere application server 8.5. Similar options must be available on other versions too.

Administrative Console -> Resources -> JDBC -> Data sources -> (Any data source which is giving this issue)
-> WebSphere Application Server data source properties -> Check Validate new connections  -> Check 
Validate existing pooled connections ->Apply -> Save -> Restart server

This approach can be bit time consuming but it got rid of the exception.

Comment: Worth to mention that there is some performance impact using this option

Answer (score 0):

Hi,
I've heard of this exception, but never got one. This can hardly be an application problem. There's probably something wrong with the data source definition or DB settings. 
So could you please provide some more information?

1. WAS version, OS / architecture, DB vendor / version, JDBC driver used
 2. Datasource / connection pool settings from WAS admin console
 3. Exception stack trace

However meanwhile you can try to set the initial connection count in connection pool to zero, so it openes a new one when asked.

Answer (score 0):

There is an troubleshooting page for that on the IBM Website.
Perhaps that will help.

They mention catching the StaleConnectionException and retry. They also provide an example how to do it.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21247168#SCETroubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem : in my case it happened when the connection has timed out on DB side, for example in the morning when 1st user connect to the application. In fact the DB connection pool min size is 1 by default, so this last connection maintained by the connection pool timed out. 
The solution was to decrease it to 0 (WAS7/Oracle). We were not facing this problem anymore.

This property is located in WAS console, Resources > JDBC > Datasources > [your DS name] > Connection pool properties

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this issue recently and found another solution.  I thought i would post if someone else comes across this thread.  The java.sql.Connection object contains an [isValid](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid(int)) function that will make a connection to the underlying database.  This allows the connection to be seen as not valid and removed.  You can then retry the connection as described in the [IBM article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21063645).

```
Context ctx = null;
DataSource dataSource = null;
Connection conn = null;
boolean retry = false;
int numOfRetries = 0;

do
{
  try
  {
    ctx = new InitialContext();
    dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("My Database");
    conn = dataSource.getConnection();

    // Make sure this connection is valid before continuing
    // This connection could be from the connection pooled 
    //   and the underlying db connection could be closed.
    if (conn.isValid(5) == false)
    {
      throw(new java.sql.SQLException("INVALID_CONNECTION"));
    }

    retry = false;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    if (numOfRetries < 2)
    {
      retry = true;
      numOfRetries++;

      // Sleep for one second before retry
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    else
    {
      retry = false;

      throw (ex);
    }
  }
} while (retry == true);
```